# making PHP join/concat (.) like JavaScript

Tags: php

I've stuck on a seems-to-be simple command join, but can't work it out.

I have a `between()` function which does the following:

```
/**
 * Checks if passed int is between $left and $right
 * @param int $left lowest value
 * @param int $right highest value
 * @param int $value actual value
 * @return bool is $value between $left and $right
 */
function between($left, $right, $value)
{
    $value = intval($value);
    return ( $value >= $left && $value <= $right );
}
```

and the usage is pretty simple:

`$int = 9;`

var_dump( between( 6, 14, $int ) );//bool(true)

Now what I want to achieve is:

```
$int = 9;

var_dump( $int.between( 6, 14 ) );//bool(true)
```

it would make more sense and would be easier to understand.

Any ideas how do I achieve this?

If `$int` would be an object which extends comparisonFunctions I could do `$int->between();` but maybe there is a way to catch what does . join?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to accomplish could you be more clear ? I mean result you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$int` is of the primitive type `int` and contains the value 9. It is not an object that has instance methods/functions. This (sadly) isn't Ruby ;)

What you want isn't possible in PHP unless you do something like this - but I wouldn't advise it:

```
class Integer {

    private $value;

    public function  __construct($value) {
        $this->setValue((int)$value);
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function between($a, $b) {
        return ($this->getValue() >= $a && $this->getValue() <= $b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you advise to use a class for Integers? In Ruby everything is an object maybe it could work out here in php?

Answer (score 5):

The `.` operator has a different meaning in Javascript and in PHP: In Javascript it is used for [property accessor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1) while PHP uses it for [string concatenation](http://php.net/language.operators.string). For property access in PHP you use the [`->` operator on objects](http://php.net/language.oop5.properties) (and the [`::` operator on classes](http://php.net/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim)) instead.

So to get the same behavior you would need to have an object value with such a method instead of a [scalar value](http://php.net/language.types.intro):

```
class Integer {
    private $value;
    public function __constructor($value) {
        $this->value = intval($value);
    }
    public function between($min, $max) {
        if (!($min instanceof Integer)) {
            $min = new Integer($min);
        }
        if (!($max instanceof Integer)) {
            $max = new Integer($max);
        }
        return $min->intValue() <= $this->value && $this->value <= $max->intValue();
    }
    public function intValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$int = new Integer(9);
var_dump($int->between(6, 14));
```

But maybe it already suffuces if you just name the function properly and switch the parameter order:

```
isInRange($val, $min, $max)
```

Comment: I'd still want to do $int.inRange(6, 14); then. It's not the naming but the concept I wanted applied to PHP, not sure if I'll dive deep enough to create classes for Integers.

Comment: @Aivaras: Then you have to use the object-oriented solution.